# Rails 5: How to access attributes through a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

A User can have many Educations and an Education can have many Users.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users_eds, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :educations, through: :users_eds, dependent: :destroy

class Education < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users_eds, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :users_eds

class UsersEd < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :education
```

In my Users List index view, I want to show the latest education.level of each User, so I write:

```
- @users.each do |user|
  = user.username
  = user.educations.last
```

However, this outputs

```
#<Education:0x007fec96d2bdf8>
```

What is the proper syntax to access the education.level or any of its attributes?

Answer (score -1):

You were almost there. You were returning the entire object, just call for the property.

```
 @users.each do |user|
      = user.username
      = user.educations.last.level
```

Comment: When I write = user.educations.last.level, I get the error: undefined method `level' for nil:NilClass